# Majority Element Leetcode with Hash Javascript Passing 1 test not the other

Tags: javascript, hash

Given an array of size n, find the majority element. The majority element is the element that appears more than ⌊ n/2 ⌋ times.

You may assume that the array is non-empty and the majority element always exists in the array.

Example 1:

Input: [3,2,3]
Output: 3
Example 2:

Input: [6,5,5]
Output: 2

My code:

```
    let newHash = {};
    let local = 0;
    let global = 0;
    
    for (let num of nums){
        if (newHash[num]){
            newHash[num] += 1
                  
        } else {
            newHash[num] = 1
        }

        for (let num in newHash){
            console.log(num)
            local = Math.max(newHash[num], newHash[num] + local)
              
        if (local > global){
            global = local
            console.log(global)
        }
        
            console.log(local)
        }
          return num
    }
  
};
```

I pass the first example [3,2,3] but fail on [6,5,5]. I know I am super close but cannot figure out how to pass.

Comment: have you copied this code? because you have literally put a section of the code inside the for loop, instead of at the bottom of the function

Comment: Num is out of scope if you return it outside of the for loop

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're solving [LeetCode's 169](https://leetcode.com/problems/majority-element/), for which this'll pass through:

```
const majorityElement = function(nums) {
    const map = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        map[nums[i]] = map[nums[i]] + 1 || 1;
        if (map[nums[i]] > nums.length >> 1) {
            return nums[i];
        }
    }

};
```

Or a bit easier to understand:

```
const majorityElement = function(nums) {
    const map = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        map[nums[i]] = map[nums[i]] + 1 || 1;
        if (map[nums[i]] > nums.length / 2) {
            return nums[i];
        }
    }

};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/majority-element/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.
- [Array Length in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

Comment: What does the length mean in this case. And what does >> do?

Answer (score 0):

Since the majority element will always exist, you can just find the element that has the highest frequency.

```js
function solve(nums){
  let newHash = {};
  let max = 0, res;
  for (let num of nums){
    if (newHash[num]){
      newHash[num] += 1;  
    } else {
      newHash[num] = 1;
    }
    if(newHash[num] > max){
      max = newHash[num];
      res = num;
    }
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(solve([6,5,5]));
```